# JSF - use different forms for different roles

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I'm writing a web application that has 2 different kind of users with different roles, I have defined the two roles and defined the site areas for the two kind of users, but I want have 2 different login forms and I don't know how define that in the  tag (in the web.xml file), because it seems that I can define only one form for authentication
How can I do that?

details: I want the if a user try to open a restricted page for a certain role, the system will redirect the user to the relative form
and if a user of a certain role tries to login with the wrong form, the system rejects her request

Comment: why do you need different form for different types of users? They will be able to use pages according to their roles.

Comment: How did you think to find out the user's role in order to determine the login form if the user hasn't logged in yet?

Comment: I have an admin area and a customer area, if a user try to access to an admin page I will to redirect it to the admin login, that is in a page with no great UI, but for the customer the login is in the "frontend" side of the website

Comment: Then you're actually not determining the login form based on user's role, but based on which restricted section the user initially visited. You should revise your question on that. What you're asking is namely impossible. The user hasn't logged in yet at that moment. Try to think logically.

Comment: ok, but it is not only a "redirection" problem, if an Admin will try to login with the "customper form" the system should say no

Comment: if I try to open the page "admin/doSomething" the system should redirect me to the "admin-login" page, and if I try to open "customer/doSomethingElse" page I should be redirected to "customer-login" page ok? AND if in the customer-login I try to use my admin-credentials the system should says to me that I can't access to the customer area

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if i'm wrong but you could try to make two login beans for programmatic login, and after username and password are submitted, you can check user roles and respond accordingly because you know which one you use on particular login page?

There is probably easier/more elegant solution tough, just can't think of it.